# "The attempted operation is not supported for the referenced object type" when installing Ubuntu WSL on Windows 10

Tags: linux, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to install Ubuntu using Windows Subsystem for Linux.  But when running Ubuntu, it always it gives me `L’opération tentée n’est pas prise en charge pour le type d’objet référencé`

English :
`The attempted operation is not supported for the referenced object type`

[image]

what is the problem?

Windows Information:
[image]

**thank you**.

Comment: Sorry my fault, Done

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you running exactly?

Comment: Windows Version : 20H2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the following commands in an elevated command prompt.

```
wsl --shutdown
netsh winsock reset
```

Manually apply the following changes to your registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinSock2\Parameters\AppId_Catalog\0408F7A3]
"AppFullPath"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\wsl.exe"
"PermittedLspCategories"=dword:80000000
```

Source:

- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/547
- https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5351